# Can I set rest API endpoints from within a theme?

Tags: theme-development, rest-api

I would like to know if it is possible to set rest API endpoints from within a theme?

I created a class to do this and made an instance of the class in the theme's `functions.php` file. This triggers the constructor which calls the `add_action()` function. When I check the path, I get a 404 message saying this endpoint is not there.

Is there a way to make sure the endpoint created as part of my theme works? I assume that the theme is not normally loaded when the REST API is called.

Comment: The theme is absolutely loaded when the REST API is called. There's no reason you can't add endpoints in a theme. Something else is wrong.

Comment: I shall continue to debug. Thank you, @JacobPeattie.

Comment: Make sure that if you're registering the rest route within a class that you're setting the callback function correctly, same as `add_action()`.

Comment: @JacobPeattie It turns out that I had a tiny typo in the callback method. Changed the type from `'POST'` to `array('POST','GET')` and saw the error message. Fixed and working.